# Windows Server 2008 Core R2 Raid status

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid

I would like to ask if there is a way how to figure out the RAID status on a running W2008SR2 Core machine. I have ICH8R Intel Controller. RaidConfig utility from intel doesnt work just like CMDTool2. RaidPart says "Unable to find any VDS hardware providers".

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with ICH8R, which is fake RAID, not hardware RAID like your tag selection would suggest. If you don't have a proper controller, you should use Windows Dynamic Disks with either software RAID 1 or 5, depending on the number of disks.

On Server Core, you would configure this with [diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)